# Como pego a localização de um marcador e guardo no banco de dados usando google map?

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps

Eu tenho um marcador no meu mapa, ele é "draggable", gostaria de saber como posso descobrir a latitude e longitude deste marcador, e posteriormente armazenar no banco de dados.

Eu li a documentação do google map api mas não encontrei como fazer isso.

@Edit:

```
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 15,
          center: franca
        });

        function CarregarEnderecoPorLatLng(latitude, longitude){
          var latlong = [latitude, longitude];
          var marker5 = new google.maps.Marker({
           position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
           map: map
       });
        return latlong;
        }

        map.addListener('click', function (e) {
          CarregarEnderecoPorLatLng(e.latLng.lat(), e.latLng.lng());
        })
```

Nessa tentativa ao clicar ele adiciona um marcador, pensei em retornar um array com a latitude e a longitude, mas estou confusa em como vou conseguir o retorno dessa latitude e longitude através dessa função.

Comment: Deixa ver se eu entendi.. Você por meio de um marcador draggable ir andando pelo google maps e posicionar em tal lugar, pegar essas coordenadas, colocar no banco para que ao dar refresh, apareça ele "static" naquela coordenada?

Comment: Exatamente, também tentei ao clicar no mapa ele adicionar um marcador, e pensei nessa função retornar a latitude e a longitude que ele recebeu através de um array, e consumir no php esse array pra fazer o insert, vou dar um edit no que eu tentei...

Comment: Entendi, olha só, eu tenho um projeto de google maps que tem uma função parecida com o que você quer. Por meio de clicks no mapa, ele envia dinamicamente a latitude e longitude para um campo input, então desse campo input eu copio e colo em um window.open e faço o cadastro do marcador, depois do cadastro ele da um auto refresh na index.php e voilá, o marcador está no local exato. Se servir, posso responder com essa minha função.

Comment: Acredito que pode ajudar sim, manda pra eu tentar ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leticia, segue a função no qual faz o que você deseja, você só terá que posicionar ela em algum lugar do seu javascript onde está o seu `initMap`

Primeiro, posicione dois inputs em algum lugar que você deseja, segue abaixo os meus:

```
<label for="latitude">Latitude:</label>
<input id="latMap"/>

<label for="longitude">Longitude:</label>
<input id="lngMap"/>
```

Então, no seu `<script>` ou arquivo **.js** do seu mapa, em algum lugar dentro da sua function `initMap` você coloca isto:

```
// Função de pegar as coordenadas com o clique no mapa
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
                    document.getElementById('latMap').value = event.latLng.lat();
                    document.getElementById('lngMap').value = event.latLng.lng();
                });

            function mapDivClicked (event) {
                var target = document.getElementById('map'),
                    posx = event.pageX - target.offsetLeft,
                    posy = event.pageY - target.offsetTop,
                    bounds = map.getBounds(),
                    neLatlng = bounds.getNorthEast(),
                    swLatlng = bounds.getSouthWest(),
                    startLat = neLatlng.latitude(),
                    endLng = neLatlng.longitude(),
                    endLat = swLatlng.latitude(),
                    startLng = swLatlng.longitude();

                document.getElementById('posX').value = posx;
                document.getElementById('posY').value = posy;
                document.getElementById('latitude').value = startLat + ((posy/350) * (endLat - startLat));
                document.getElementById('longitude').value = startLng + ((posx/500) * (endLng - startLng));
            };
```

E então, você não esqueça de referenciar isso no seu link da api do google maps, vou colocar a minha e você pode reparar que tem umas referencias usando o **&**, você adiciona assim `&libraries=geometry&callback=initMap`

Mas vou colocar o meu como está para você ver, basta colocar sua chave API ali e colocar no seu index.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=SUA_CHAVE_API&v=3&libraries=geometry&callback=initMap" defer > </script>
```

Se tiver alguma dúvida, me responda abaixo que vamos trabalhando juntos para alinhar tudo.

Comment: apareceu a latitude e a longitude, mas estou com dificuldades de passar essa variável para uma variável php, eu tentei:

var latitude = startLat + ((posy/350) * (endLat - startLat));
                            var longitude = startLng + ((posx/500) * (endLng - startLng));

<?php
  $latitude = "<script>document.write(latitude)</script>";
  echo "$latitude";

 ?>

No console retorna que latitude não é definida

Comment: Neste caso, como se trata de um campo que irá receber um valor após o click do mouse, ele começa como nulo. Acredito que por isso que a variável latitude está indefinida. Mas qual o seu objetivo? Você quer pegar os valores destes dois inputs para fazer um cadastro?

Comment: Minha idéia é armazenar a latitude e a longitude dos dois campos no bd

Comment: Só uma pergunta, você já tem esse sistema de cadastro e processo pra mostrar os dados do bd no mapa pronto?

Comment: Fiz com um form:
  <form action="" method="post">

    <label for="latitude">Latitude:</label>
    <input id="latMap" name="latitude"/>

    <label for="longitude">Longitude:</label>
    <input id="lngMap" name="longitude"/>
    <input type="submit">
    </form>


    <?php
    $latitude = $_POST["latitude"];

    $longitude = $_POST["longitude"];

    echo "$latitude";
    ?>

acredito que consigo prosseguir de agora em diante, caso contrário abro um novo tópico com a nova dúvida, muito obrigado.

Comment: Ainda não tenho, estou só pensando na lógica principal, acredito que agora consigo

Comment: Entendi, olha só, posso te passar um link para o vídeo do pessoal que me ajudou a fazer essa comunicação google maps com o mysqli, se quiser, posso te passar.

Comment: Me passe por favor, qualquer novo material de estudo é bem vindo

Comment: Aqui Leticia, esse link é o primeiro onde instrui detalhadamente Como usar o Google Maps com PHP e MYSQLi: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ET5E0G3vK4

E esse é a parte 2 de como cadastrá-lo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=auWRQ9KzzRM

Comment: vou assistir!!!